# Issues with maps and their entries in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, recursion

I have a recursive function that takes a Map as single parameter. It then adds new entries to that Map and calls itself with this larger Map. Please ignore the return values for now. The function isn't finished yet. Here's the code:

```
def breadthFirstHelper( found: Map[AIS_State,(Option[AIS_State], Int)] ): List[AIS_State] = {
  val extension =
   for( 
     (s, v) <- found; 
     next <- this.expand(s) if (! (found contains next) )
   ) yield (next -> (Some(s), 0))

  if ( extension.exists( (s -> (p,c)) => this.isGoal( s ) ) )
    List(this.getStart)
  else
    breadthFirstHelper( found ++ extension )
}
```

In **extension** are the new entries that shall get added to the map. Note that the for-statement generates an iterable, not a map. But those entries shall later get added to the original map for the recursive call. In the break condition, I need to test whether a certain value has been generated inside **extension**. I try to do this by using the exists method on **extension**. But the syntax for extracting values from the map entries (the stuff following the yield) doesn't work.

Questions:

1. How do I get my break condition (the boolean statement to the if) to work?
2. Is it a good idea to do recursive work on a immutable Map like this? Is this good functional style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted for me to follow, whatever Oxbow Lakes might think.

I'd like first to clarify one point: there is no break condition in for-comprehensions. They are not loops like C's (or Java's) `for`.

What an `if` in a for-comprehension means is a guard. For instance, let's say I do this:

```
for {i <- 1 to 10
     j <- 1 to 10
     if i != j
} yield (i, j)
```

The loop isn't "stopped" when the condition is false. It simply *skips* the iterations for which that condition is false, and proceed with the true ones. Here is another example:

```
for {i <- 1 to 10
     j <- 1 to 10
     if i % 2 != 0
} yield (i, j)
```

You said you don't have side-effects, so I can skip a whole chapter about side effects and guards on for-comprehensions. On the other hand, reading a blog post I made recently on [Strict Ranges](http://dcsobral.blogspot.com/2009/10/strict-ranges.html) is not a bad idea.

So... give up on break conditions. They can be made to work, but they are not functional. Try to rephrase the problem in a more functional way, and the need for a break condition will be replaced by something else.

Next, Oxbow is correct in that `(s -> (p,c) =>` isn't allowed because there is no extractor defined on an object called `->`, but, alas, even `(a :: b) =>` would not be allowed, because there is no pattern matching going on in functional literal parameter declaration. You must simply state the parameters on the left side of `=>`, without doing any kind of decomposition. You may, however, do this:

```
if ( extension.exists( t => val (s, (p,c)) = t; this.isGoal( s ) ) )
```

Note that I replaced `->` with `,`. This works because `a -> b` is a syntactic sugar for `(a, b)`, which is, itself, a syntactic sugar for `Tuple2(a, b)`. As you don't use neither `p` nor `c`, this works too:

```
if ( extension.exists( t => val (s, _) = t; this.isGoal( s ) ) )
```

Finally, your recursive code is perfectly fine, though probably not optimized for tail-recursion. For that, you either make your method `final`, or you make the recursive function private to the method. Like this:

```
final def breadthFirstHelper
```

or

```
def breadthFirstHelper(...) {
  def myRecursiveBreadthFirstHelper(...) { ... }
  myRecursiveBreadthFirstHelper(...)
}
```

On Scala 2.8 there is an annotation called `@TailRec` which will tell you if the function can be made tail recursive or not. And, in fact, it seems there will be a flag to display warnings about functions that *could* be made tail-recursive if slightly changed, such as above.

**EDIT**

Regarding Oxbow's solution using `case`, that's a function or partial function literal. It's type will depend on what the inference requires. In that case, because that's that `exists` takes, a function. However, one must be careful to ensure that there will always be a match, otherwise you get an exception. For example:

```
scala> List(1, 'c') exists { case _: Int => true }
res0: Boolean = true

scala> List(1, 'c') exists { case _: String => true }
scala.MatchError: 1
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:5)
        ... (stack trace elided)    

scala> List(1, 'c') exists { case _: String => true; case _ => false }
res3: Boolean = false

scala> ({ case _: Int => true } : PartialFunction[AnyRef,Boolean])
res5: PartialFunction[AnyRef,Boolean] = <function1>

scala> ({ case _: Int => true } : Function1[Int, Boolean])
res6: (Int) => Boolean = <function1>
```

**EDIT 2**

The solution Oxbow proposes does use pattern matching, because it is based on function literals using `case` statements, which do use pattern matching. When I said it was not possible, I was speaking of the syntax `x => s`.

Comment: I think you missunderstood what I meant by "break condition", which shall be the condition to break the recursion. The second part of your answer is pretty insightful, though. Can you please give a comment on oxbow's solution using "case", too?

Comment: @Daniel - you are wrong to say that there is no pattern-matching going on in my example, perhaps I should have clarified! You can certainly use `exists { case x :: xs =>`

Comment: Did I say in your example? I meant the original question.

Answer (score 4):

When using a pattern-match (e.g. against a `Tuple2`) in a function, you need to use braces `{}` and the `case` statement.

```
if (extension.exists { case (s,_) => isGoal(s) } )
```

The above also uses the fact that it is more clear when matching to use the wildcard `_` for any allowable value (which you subsequently do not care about). The `case xyz` gets compiled into a `PartialFunction` which in turn extends from `Function1` and hence can be used as an argument to the `exists` method.

As for the style, I am not functional programming expert but this seems like it will be compiled into a iterative form (i.e. it's tail-recursive) by *scalac*. There's nothing which says *"recursion with Maps is bad"* so why not?

**Note** that `->` is a method on `Any` (via implicit conversion) which creates a `Tuple2` - it is **not a case class** like `::` or `!` and hence cannot be used in a `case` pattern match statement. This is because:

```
val l: List[String] = Nil
l match {
  case x :: xs =>
}
```

Is really shorthand/sugar for

```
case ::(x, xs) =>
```

Similarly `a ! b` is equivalent to `!(a, b)`. Of course, you may have written your own case class `->`...

**Note2**: as Daniel says below, you cannot in any case use a pattern-match in a function definition; so while the above *partial function* is valid, the following function is not:

```
(x :: xs) =>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Seems I still have to come to this use of the case statement in Programming in Scala.

Comment: @ziggystar - to be honest, you'll have to wait for *Daniel* (Sobral) to come along and give you the definitive answer on the `{ case` syntax because I'm not 100% clear on it! I think it has something to do with the fact that `PartialFunction` extends `Function1` (which seems a bit silly to me) and the case statement above gets compiled into a `PartialFunction`

Comment: Actually, I said the same thing about `PartialFunction` and `Function1` in the presence of the might Paul Phillips, and got promptly corrected. The compiler generates either a `PartialFunction` or a `Function1` depending on the type hints, which can be verified by using reflection to check what methods are available.